# Get title from <a> Selenium Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver

I want to copy some Domains out of an internet list. The Problem is, that when the domain gets too long, it gets abbreviated with a "...". But the Full Name is still in the title.

HTML Code:

```
    <td class="field_domain"><a href="/goto/1/1qltz/7/" target="_blank" title="angelfreunde-bueschfeld-saarland.de" class="namelinks" id="linksdd-domain1qltz">angelfreunde-bueschfeld-saarla...de</a>
```

My Code (domains is the important part):

```
    for k in range(pagesroundup):
    domains = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/td[1]')
    domainpops = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/td[5]')
    birthyears = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/td[7]')
    archivecrawls = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/td[8]')
    adddates = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/td[19]')
    wikilinks = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/td[21]')
    enddates = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/td[22]')

    for i in range(len(domains)):
        df_rpg = df_rpg.append({
        'Domain':domains[i].text,
        'Verweisende Domains':domainpops[i].text,
        'Geburtsjahr':birthyears[i].text,
        'Archive Crawls':archivecrawls[i].text,
        'Wikilinks':wikilinks[i].text,
        'Hinzugefügt am':adddates[i].text,
        'Läuft ab am':enddates[i].text}, ignore_index=True)
```

What can I do, that not the Text with the "..." will be extracted, but the title, where the full domain stands.

The Solution below does not work!

```py
    for k in range(pagesroundup):
    domains = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/td[1]')
    domainpops = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/td[5]')
    birthyears = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/td[7]')
    archivecrawls = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/td[8]')
    adddates = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/td[19]')
    wikilinks = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/td[21]')
    enddates = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/td[22]')

    for i in range(len(domains)):
        df_rpg = df_rpg.append({
        'Domain':domains[i].get_attrubute('title'),
        'Verweisende Domains':domainpops[i].text,
        'Geburtsjahr':birthyears[i].text,
        'Archive Crawls':archivecrawls[i].text,
        'Wikilinks':wikilinks[i].text,
        'Hinzugefügt am':adddates[i].text,
        'Läuft ab am':enddates[i].text}, ignore_index=True)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: can you share the page(s) link(s)?

Comment: @Prophet [expireddomains.net](https://www.expireddomains.net/expired-domains/)